# System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object: ()

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, attachment, emailmessage

I'm getting the error at line 12 i.e List{attachment} attachmentsToInsert = new List{Attachment}(); Could someone help, please? I've enabled the enhance email.

> Error message: Apex trigger CopyAttachmentstoOpps caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: CopyAttachmentstoOpps: execution of AfterInsert
>
> caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object: ()

```
public class CopyAttachmentToOpptyController {
 
    // Constructor - this only really matters if the autoRun function doesn't work right
    private final Opportunity o;
    public CopyAttachmentToOpptyController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.o = (Opportunity)stdController.getRecord();
    }
     
    // Code we will invoke on page load.
    public PageReference autoRun() {
    
        List<Attachment> attachmentsToInsert = new List<Attachment>(); 
        String theId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
 
        if (theId == null) {
            // Display the Visualforce page's content if no Id is passed over
            return null;
        }      
        
        Set<ID> emailMsgID = new Set<ID>();
        for (EmailMessage em:[SELECT Id, ParentId, relatedtoid FROM EmailMessage where relatedtoid =:theId or ParentId =:theId]) {
            emailMsgID.add(em.Id);
        }
        system.debug('emailMsgID-->'+emailMsgID);
        
        List<Attachment> attachmentList = [SELECT Id, ParentId, name, body from Attachment where ParentId IN: emailMsgID];
        List<Attachment> alreadyAttached = [SELECT Id, ParentId, name, body from Attachment where ParentId =: theId];
        
        system.debug('attachmentList -->'+attachmentList);
        system.debug('alreadyAttached -->'+alreadyAttached);
               
        Set<ID> skipAttachment = new Set<ID>();
        for (Attachment a : attachmentList){
            for(Attachment al :alreadyAttached){  
                if(a.name == al.name){      
                    skipAttachment.add(a.Id);
                }
            }
        }
        
        for (Attachment a : attachmentList){  
            if(!skipAttachment.contains(a.Id)){      
                Attachment att = new Attachment(ParentId = theId, Name = a.name, Body = a.body);
                attachmentsToInsert.add(att);
            }
        }
        
        system.debug('attachmentsToInsert-->'+attachmentsToInsert);
        
        if (attachmentsToInsert.size() > 0) {
            insert attachmentsToInsert;
        }        
               
        // Redirect the user back to the original page
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/' + theId);
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
        return pageRef;
 
    }
 
}
```

Comment: Provide the trigger code you have on Attachment as well. The line 12 in what you've posted is not the problem.

Comment: It seems that the error is not from the code you pasted, but from an after insert trigger.

Comment: @MauricioOliveira You're correct. I just checked with my development team and they said they're also working on the same object. It caused the issue. Thank you again

Comment: @Gidy that did not cause the issue, it exposed it. Your code needs updating since it is being called from a trigger. Get the id from pagereference in the appropriate constructor and pass it to the method. Then a trigger can call it as well without error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line 12 seems to be List attachmentsToInsert = new List(); witch **cannot** throw that error.

Since the error message says the trace is from a trigger and I don't see anything in your code to execute the trigger....

The next logical line that could throw the error would be

```
String theId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
```

If the trigger happens while the initiating user is NOT on a VF page `ApexPages.currentPage()` will be null.

You will need to rethink your code to handle both VF initiated transactions and non VF initiated transactions mainly by passing in the Id to the class method vs trying to get if from a page reference that may not exist